# Why doesn't my result stay after I submit my form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to add two numbers that are put in input fields. Then I want to display the result but the result disappears right after.

```js
function add() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    
    var result = num1 + num2;
    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    display.append(result);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
            <form action="" id="form">
                <label for="num1">Number 1</label>                
                    <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1">
                <label for="num2">Number 2</label>
                    <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2">
                <button id="submit" onclick="add()">Add</button>
            </form>
            <p id="display"></p>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Because your form is being submitted after you click Add button. Your need to `return false` from the function or add `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: It worked, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `event.preventDefault()` to prevent this behavior, and convert the values to numeric form before the addition:

```js
function add(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    if(num1 && num2){
         var result = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
         var display = document.getElementById("display");
         display.append(result);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
            <form action="" id="form">
                <label for="num1">Number 1</label>                
                    <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1">
                <label for="num2">Number 2</label>
                    <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2">
                <button id="submit" onclick="add(event)">Add</button>
            </form>
            <p id="display"></p>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```